# TUGboat open-access survey

Tags: discussion, tug

TUG is considering making all publications to TUGboat open-access.  To this end they have started a survey.  The survey also addresses non-members, so to be representative it needs as many participants as possible.

While not being directly about the site itself, I think this would greatly influence the TeX community which this site is for.

> Hello TUG member!
>
> The TUG board is considering making TUGboat a fully open access journal,
>   with all material immediately available online to anyone, upon publication.
>   (We expect the print journal to continue to be produced unchanged.)
>
> We only want to do this if it will help TUG, not hurt it. Memberships
>   are what pay the bills, and we just cannot predict whether this change
>   would cause a crash in memberships or not.
>
> Thus, we ask you to carefully consider and answer the one-question survey at
>
> http://tug.org/TUGboat/survey.html
>
> about the effect this change would have on your renewing your membership.
>   It is completely anonymous. (Please only submit it once.)
>
> Thanks for your support of TUG,
>
> TUG Board of Directors

Comment: @marmot This is how meta works: announcements like this one are fine.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I don't think it is a good idea to discuss the _contents_ of the survey here. Let's keep that to the chat maybe. (The point is, there was a long discussion about this at the TUG AGM in Rio, it's complicated and it would easily clutter the comments completely; that's not what comments are for.)

Comment: @yo' OK, thanks for letting me know. I deleted my comments. (Personally I am not sure if that's the best way of doing this, I guess there is a significant fraction of users of the main site that does not really look at meta, but of course this is just my impression, not substantiated by any real data.)

Comment: @marmot Joseph has made the question featured, so it appears in the right pane on the main site now.

Comment: How can non-members comment on the changes effect on renewing their memberships?

Comment: @cfr It is optional.  You don't have to select anything in the category that doesn't apply to you.

Comment: @HenriMenke But it's a one-question survey?

Comment: @cfr What I see at the link is that for non-members, the question is about joining, rather than renewing. ("more likely to join  /  less likely to join  /  no effect on joining")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The survey is closed, the results are available here: https://tug.org/TUGboat/survey.html